# Полученные значений из динамически создаваемых контролов C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Не знаю как получить значения динамически создаваемых контролов.

Описание:

Есть программа, которая будет парсить CSR(запрос на сертификат) и сравнивать его с шаблоном. Парсится в json, шаблон тоже в json. И вот вопрос.
Я для удобства редактирования пользователем, хочу добавить форму. Форма при создании контролов берёт данные из json:

```
            temp_comboBox_valueType.Location = new Point(12, 60);
            temp_comboBox_valueType.Size = new Size(70, 22);
            temp_comboBox_valueType.Name = "temp_comboBox_valueType_" + itemIndex;
            temp_comboBox_valueType.Items.AddRange(valueTypeCollection);
            temp_comboBox_valueType.SelectedItem = "Name";

            temp_textBox_typeValue.Location = new Point(87, 60);
            temp_textBox_typeValue.Size = new Size(150, 22);
            temp_textBox_typeValue.Text = fieldItem[itemIndex].Name;
            temp_textBox_typeValue.Name = "temp_textBox_typeValue_" + itemIndex;

            temp_comboBox_conditionType.Location = new Point(242, 60);
            temp_comboBox_conditionType.Size = new Size(70, 20);
            temp_comboBox_conditionType.Items.AddRange(conditionTypeCollection);

            temp_textBox_value.Location = new Point(319, 60);
            temp_textBox_value.Size = new Size(150, 22);
            temp_textBox_value.Name = "temp_textBox_value_" + itemIndex;
            temp_textBox_value.Text = fieldItem[itemIndex].Value;

            temp_checkBox_regexp.Location = new Point(474, 60);
            temp_checkBox_regexp.Size = new Size(64, 22);
            temp_checkBox_regexp.Text = "RegExp";

            temp_checkBox_enabled.Location = new Point(543, 60);
            temp_checkBox_enabled.Size = new Size(81, 22);
            temp_checkBox_enabled.Text = "Включить";
```

И так для каждого item в оригинальном json файле. Получается примерно так:
[image: пример кода]

И вот суть. После того как пользователь создать ещё одно условие, в котором разные контролы(listbox,checkbox,textbox) - генерируется ещё одна строка контролов, в которую пользователь вводит и выбирает данные. Как от туда забрать значения по нажатию конопки для последующей их сериализации?

Я вижу вариант, но уверен насколько он правильный. Не слишком сильно ли это будет говнокод. А то уже куда больше:

Моё виденье. Получить список всех контролов формы через `Controls.Find("name",false)` - где я подставлю каждый возможный контрол и из него извлекаю то, что мне надо.

Или при инициализации контролов добавлять в Dictonary ссылки на нужные поля в контроле(Text, SelectedItem, Checked). А при сохранении их извлекать.

Дайте совет, пожалуйста.

Comment: запихнуть динамические контролы в `panel` (они ж у вас как то скролится будут?) и с нее уже забирать детей

Comment: Так вы, когда строку контролов генерируете, сами контролы-то в подходящую коллекцию сохраняйте!

Comment: Ну и про пользовательские контролы не забывайте...

Answer (score 0):

Короче, да. Собрал коллекцию контролов и с ними уже работаю. Как это нашептал мне индусский б-г:

Объявил коллекцию:

```
    public static List<Control[]> controlValueCollection = new List<Control[]>();

    // в коде выше есть пример моих контролов. Собираю их в пучок и в коллекцию

    result = new Control[] { comboBox_type, textBox_typeValue, comboBox_conditionType, textBox_value, checkBox_regexp, checkBox_enabled };
    controlValueCollection.Add(result); 
List<Control[]> collection = new List<Control[]>(); 
collection = controlValueCollection; 

foreach (Control[] items in collection)
{
    TemplateItem templateItem = new TemplateItem();
    CheckBox ch_enabled = (CheckBox)items[5];
    if (ch_enabled.Checked == true)
    {
        foreach (var control in items)
        {
            switch (control.Name)
            {
                case "typeValue":
                    if (items[0].Text == "Name")
                    {
                        Oid oid = new Oid
                        {
                            FriendlyName = control.Text
                        };
                        templateItem.Name = control.Text;
                        templateItem.OID = oid.Value;
                    }
                    else if (items[0].Text == "OID")
                    {
                        Oid oid = new Oid
                        {
                            Value = control.Text
                        };
                        templateItem.OID = control.Text;
                        templateItem.Name = oid.FriendlyName;
                    }
                    break;
                case "condition":
                    templateItem.ConditionType = control.Text;
                    break;
                case "value":
                    templateItem.Value = control.Text;
                    break;
                case "regexp":
                    var checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
                    templateItem.RegExp = checkBox.Checked;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Изначальный код по ходу решения менялся. Но суть такова:
При создании контролов задаю им имена;
помещаю в порядке их создания в коллекцию;
извлекаю при сохранении пачки контролов в том же порядке(FIFO)
свитчом прогоняю поле Name и выполняю нужный код

Ремарка: Для некоторых контролов существуют специфические методы, так при сохранении проверяется стоит ли галка в контроле `CheckBox ch_enabled` - для этого надо переопределить класс как CheckBox - `CheckBox ch_enabled = (CheckBox)items[5];`
Иначе `ch_enabled.Checked == true` вам не сделать.
На этом вроде всё.

Если появятся башковитые ребята, которые скажут, как, всё-таки, делать правильно - велкам, как говорится, очень вас жду.

Comment: Эх... не нравится мне ваш swithc... Я бы на вашем месте, создал бы словарь Dictionary<string,Action<Control>>, где ключ- это название вашего контрола, а значение делегат обработки, а в коде бы делал так dict["value"](control). Имхо было бы красивее.

Comment: Немного не понял про делегат обработки. Можно пример небольшой?

Comment: для начала вы знаете, что такое делегат?

Comment: Ещё не приходилось практиковать их. Как-то так, но читал. Видимо, имеется виду, что я объявлю `Action<Control> conrtolValue;`. Буду в него добавлять метод извлечения значения из контрола и как-то в словаре это все крутить. Но т.к. с делегатами не работал, то сам буду делать вещи ещё страшнее чем switch.